# Reusing input String[] with values from arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

I have the following code which sorts a mixed array of items while maintaining the position of types:

For example:

```
[20, "abc", "moose", 2,1] turns into  [1, "abc", "moose", 2, 20]
```

Algorithm:

```
 public class Algorithm {
        public static String[] sortMixedArray(String[] input){
            if (input.length == 0){
                return input;
            }

            // make new arraylist for strings and numbers respectively 
            List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // add values to the arraylist they belong to
            for (String item : input){
                if (NumberUtils.isNumber(item)){
                    numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(item));
                } else {
                    strs.add(item);
                }
            }

            // sort for O(nlogn)
            Collections.sort(strs);
            Collections.sort(numbers);

            // reuse original array
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                if (NumberUtils.isNumber(input[i])) {
                    input[i] = String.valueOf(numbers.remove(0));
                } else {
                    input[i] = strs.remove(0);
                }   
            }

            return input;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] test = new String[] {"moo", "boo"};
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortMixedArray(test)));

        }
```

I have a two-part question:

**1.** Is switching between array and arraylist efficient? That is, should I have used arrays everywhere instead of arraylist if my input MUST be an array.

**2.** What is the best way to place arraylist items back into a array? I am checking for type, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.If you do it the way you have it in your code then it's perfectly fine. If you know beforehand how many elements you will have it's better to use arrays but thats not the case in your example.

2.The best and easiest way is to use the `toArray()` function of the `List` interface.

```
ArrayList<String> list = ...;
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

But this won't work for your code since you are merging two lists into one array. You can still improve your code a bit because you do not actually have to remove the items from the lists when putting them back in the array. This safes some computation since removing the first element from an `ArrayList` is very inefficient (O(N) runtime per remove operation).

```
    for (int i = 0, s = 0, n = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (NumberUtils.isNumber(input[i])) {
            input[i] = Integer.toString(numbers.get(n++));
        } else {
            input[i] = strs.get(s++);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. No but it highly unlikely to matter unless you have a million of elements.
2. Do whatever you believe is simplest and most efficient for you, the developer.

BTW the least efficient operations is `remove(0)` which is `O(N)` so you might change that.